# Helper function to retrieve a value from an object fails with more than one item in the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a helper function to retrieve a user's name or email from the redux store when the user's UID is passed as an argument

```
From the store

console.log(typeof users) //object
console.log(users)

[
    0: {
        displayName: "User One"
        email: "userone@example.com"
        id: "c9E5RfPVVxMNPz3MsORs76cG46G3"
    },
    1: {
        displayName: "User Two"
        email: "usertwo@example.com"
        id: "mbuPoIcEMOhEvSB23IRqj5AIbZn2"
    }
]
```

```
// getUserDetails.js

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export function getUserDetails(searchKey) {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.users);
  console.log(users)
  console.log(typeof users)
  return (
    users &&
    searchKey &&
    users.filter(function (obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
        return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
      });
    })
  );
}
```

And it is used by my `@devexpress/dx-react-grid` CRUD tables, by taking the field `createdBy: fdsj75g43hfihsdhi` and returning a name or email, like this:

```
  const UserNameFormatter = ({ value }) => {
    return getUserDetails(value)[0].displayName;
  };
```

The function works great with only one user, but as soon as I add another user to Firestore, the function throws an error:

```
TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function
(anonymous function)
src/utils/getUserDetails.js:10
   7 |   searchKey &&
   8 |   users.filter(function (obj) {
   9 |     return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
> 10 |       return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
     | ^  11 |     });
  12 |   })
  13 | );
```

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I guess what would help us most is if you can provide us an example of what `users` looks like (please redact any real/identifying data!)

Comment: @Nick thanks for the responses. I've edited the question to add an example of the object ```users``` I'm getting from the store.

Comment: It seems that you're expecting each key to be a string, but that's not always the case. Maybe you can do a check before using the `includes` method like this: `return typeof obj[key] === "string" && obj[key].includes(searchKey);`

Comment: @Nick that worked, thanks very much. I didn't think of that, working great now, thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! I posted a formal answer, I'd appreciate if you upvoted it and marked it as correct so I can get those sweet S.O. reputation points!

Comment: @nick, done thanks for your help. Now I just need to catch an error if the user has been deleted but still has a docs in the database...back to the books! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're expecting each key to be a string, but that's not always the case.

I recommend doing a check before using the includes method like this:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export function getUserDetails(searchKey) {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.users);
  console.log(users)
  console.log(typeof users)
  return (
    users &&
    searchKey &&
    users.filter(function (obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
        return typeof obj[key] === "string" && obj[key].includes(searchKey);
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  const UserNameFormatter = ({ value }) => {
    return getUserDetails(value[0].displayName);
  };
```

Example:

```js
var temp1 = [
    {
        displayName: "User One",
        email: "userone@example.com",
        id: "c9E5RfPVVxMNPz3MsORs76cG46G3",
    },
    {
        displayName: "User Two",
        email: "usertwo@example.com",
        id: "mbuPoIcEMOhEvSB23IRqj5AIbZn2"
    }
]


function getUserDetails(searchKey) {

  return (
    temp1.filter(function (obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
        return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
      });
    })
  );
}



console.log(getUserDetails(temp1[1].id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this threw the same error. I'll go with @nick's answer above. Thank you